# Pre-2011 sci fi adventure book (series?) starring a young female protagonist who visits an alien market with her younger sibling

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read it in junior high and I'm certain it was written for an 11-15 audience. I remember the cover being pinkish/violet and may have had characters on it. If so, the characters don't take up much real estate. The cover looked like a drawing or painting, not photography.

I remember it being about a young girl who travels through space, or at least on an alien planet. She is accompanied by her younger sibling, I believe. I also remember there being sequels, which I never picked up.

The only vivid memory I have of the story is the girl trying trying to navigate a busy alien market. The aliens are described really well. There are other humans here and an older human man even helps her. I know this isn't super helpful but that's really all I remember.

I think the younger sibling might be her little sister. I have no idea how they ended up at the market or what they're doing, but yeah. I've tried Google and Goodreads and looked at a dozen lists. I can't find it anywhere.

There is also a problem of her not being able to understand what the aliens are saying because obviously they're not speaking English and she needs a portable translator or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it: [*High Wizardry*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176534.High_Wizardry) (1990) by Diane Duane, book 3 of the *Young Wizards* series.

Goodreads came through with its lists. I was right about the little sister and this is part of a series. The sisters get chased across the galaxy, so there are aliens. It also involves magic, which I did not remember. What a wild ride.

[image: book cover, red-haired young girl sitting and holding a book]

Comment: Ah, that does sound like a good match in retrospect. You can self-accept in about 30 hours by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. This will be closed as a duplicate since this story has been identified before, but that's not a censure, just how we tie our questions and answers together.